# Como zerar as funções de um evento onclick?

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma pagina modal com os botoes fechar e minimizar.

O botão minimizar possui uma função `onclick` para alterar seu fundo entre maximizar e minimizar e outra `tooglefulscreen` para sair e entrar do modo tela cheia.

o botão fechar possui a função `exitfullscreen` para fechar a pagina em tela cheia.

acredito que meu problema seja que apos executar a função o botão que foi clicado nao retorna para a imagem original, ele permanece o mesmo da ultima função executada.

evento 1 

page modal > minimizar.png > click > altera para > **maximizar.png**

page modal > fechar.png> click > fecha a janela modal

evento 2  **( o evento deveria começar igual ao evento 1 )**

page modal > **maximizar.png** > click > altera para > **minimizar.png**

page modal > fechar.png > click > fechar janela modal

evento 3 **( o evento deveria começa igual ao evento 2 )**

page modal > **minimizar.png** > click > altera para > maximizar.png

page modal > fechar.png > click > fechar janela modal

O que acontece é que apos o fim dessas funções ou seja apos fechar a pagina modal através do botão fechar, o fundo do botão minimizar permanece o mesmo da sua ultima função, por exemplo, se fecho a pagina sem clicar no botão "minimizar" e apos isso abro a pagina, a pagina abre com o botão minimizar ativo para apos ser clicado sair do modo tela cheia e alterar a imagem para maximizar, mas se aperto no botão minimizar e minimizo e depois disso fecho a pagina quando abro ela de novo o botão maximizar aparece ativo em tela cheia e o efeito fica invertido.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#botao1', function() {
  $("#status").html("mudando o nome do botão para botao2");
  $(this).attr("id", "botao2").html("");
});
$(document).on('click', '#botao2', function() {
  $("#status").html("retornando o nome do botão para botao1");
  $(this).attr("id", "botao1").html("");
});

function toggleFullScreen(id) {
  var div = document.getElementById(id);
  if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) ||
    (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
    if (div.requestFullScreen) {
      div.requestFullScreen();
    } else if (div.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      div.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (div.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
      div.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
  } else {
    if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
      document.cancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
      document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    }
  }
}

function exitFullscreen() {
  if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
  } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  }
}
```

```css
#botao1 {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  top: 5px;
  right: 110px;
  background: url(Img/btn-maximizar.png) no-repeat;
}

#botao1:hover {
  background: url(Img/btn-maximizar-2.png) no-repeat;
}

#botao2 {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  top: 5px;
  right: 110px;
  background: url(Img/btn-minimizar.png) no-repeat;
}

#botao2:hover {
  background: url(img/btn-minimizar-2.png)no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="botao1" onclick="toggleFullScreen('full')"></button>
<button class="fechar" onclick="exitFullscreen();">X</button>
```

Comment: Estou editando a sua pergunta, para tentar melhorar a visualização e entendimento da mesma.

Comment: obrigado @MarceloBoni voce consegue respondê-la ? parece simples de solucionar com uma função onblur mas não tenho esse conhecimento

Comment: Na verdade, acredito que a explicação da pergunta ficou bem confusa, os códigos estão ok, se puder tentar editar e mudar um pouco a explicação... fique mais fácil obter uma boa resposta

Comment: De qualquer modo, hoje mais tarde, se ainda não tiver sido respondida, eu tento dar um help

Comment: adicionei mais detalhes, pode me informa onde fica confuso ?

Comment: alguém pode ajudar ??

Comment: @MarceloBoni consegue responder ?